# How to add an image in Jekyll post

Tags: image, jekyll

I need to add an Image in a Jekyll post.

I have created an image folder in the root directory called `images`.

I have the post in markdown as follows:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Restraunt"
date:   2023-08-02 01:05:22 -0400
categories: jekyll update
---

PARAGRAPH 01

![Image](/images/IMG_20231109_171049.jpg)
```

I am able to see the post once I run the command `bundle exec jekyll serve`. This opens the post and I am able to see the image.

[image]

But when I deploy the code and visit the site I get the following result:

[image]

I look in the logs and see the following error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

[image]

I inspect the error is due to the image unable to load to the server or the server is unable to find the image file.

Any help or comment will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There can be 2 issues: 1) the image is not deployed or 2) the url of the image is incorrect on the post page. So can you show what is the "<img src=.." in the post html? And can you check if the image is present under some url? Probably under domain_name/images/IMG_20231109_171049.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link presented which solved my issue.

It was a path variable issue.

https://mademistakes.com/mastering-jekyll/site-url-baseurl/